# Is it possible to enable rounding to zero or rounding to minus infinity in ifort?

Tags: linux, floating-point, fortran, rounding, intel-fortran

I have a scenario where I want the compiler to round the floating point values towards zero or towards minus infinity. It needs to be done only through compiler options and I was unable to find any compiler options regarding this where as a similar method is available for xlf compiler for AIX platform.

Is there any way to do this in Linux using ifort compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The floating-point options for the Intel FORTRAN compiler are listed [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/463906). I do not see any option that controls rounding mode.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know if a minus infinity flag exists, but the [flush to zero](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/flush-to-zero-mode-in-fortran-on-intel-architecture) flag, `-ftz`, seems to be half of what you want. A simple test follows:

```
program testftz
   implicit none
   real :: x
   integer :: i

   x = 1.0
   do i=1,50
      print *,i,x
      x = x/10.0
   enddo
end program testftz
```

Compiling this *without* `-ftz` gives a small value of `1.4012985e-45` at the 46th step before dropping it off to zero. Compiling it *with* `-ftz` gives a small value of `9.999999e-38` at the 38th step before dropping off to zero.

Comment: Flush to zero is a “feature” (deficiency) in some processors where they change subnormal values to zero, to compensate for the poor performance they provide for handling subnormal values correctly. This features does not affect rounding in operations that do not involve subnormal values, and it is not at all what the question asks for.